# Proper wildcard Disallow for robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, google-search

I am trying to disallow a specific page and its parameters along with a parameter on the entire site. Below I have the exact examples.

We now have a page that will redirect and track exteral urls. Any external URL we want to track will be linked like `/redirect?u=http://example.com` We do not want to add `rel="nofollow"` to every link.

Last but not least (our biggest seo and index issue) is every single page has an auto generate URL to disable or enable mobile. So it can be on any page like `/?mobileVersion=off` (or on) or `/accounts?login_to=%2Fdashboard&mobileVersion=off`

Basically the easy way to disallow the two parameters would be to disallow `mobileVersion` and `u` from any page. (`u` is the parameter needed to redirect the URL and is only valid on `/redirect`)

My current `robots.txt` config:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /redirect
Disallow: / *?*mobileVersion=off
```

If you want to see our full `robots.txt` files its located at http://spicethymeinc.com/robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

you could change

```
Disallow: / *?*mobileVersion=off
```

to

```
Disallow: /*mobileVersion=off
```

but it looks like it should work.

I'm going off the wildcard section and examples on this page:
http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/

edit:  I have tested with the googlebot and googlebot mobile.  The are blocked by both your current robots.txt and my suggested change.  [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) has a handy robots checker you can use to test.

Comment: Hi, so I wouldn't need a '?' before the parameter? Also, if I wanted to disallow the entire parameter would be '/*mobileVersion' ?

Comment: No you don't need the ? to block access to the urls in your example.  If you had an url with mobileVersion=off before the query string it too would be blocked though.  Yes /*mobileVersion would block any urls with that parameter, whether it be on or off or any other value.

Comment: I appreciate the help! @iceburg I'm going to make the updates. I never saw the feature in Webmaster Tools.